# Kubernetes HA master setup

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have configured two separate masters in Kubernetes in Google Cloud..How to connect both masters for high availabilty Mater(for resiliency)? Anyone can help?

Reagrds,
Rishabh

Comment: can you please post following Kubenetes config files:
- /etc/kubernetes/config
- /etc/kubernetes/apiserver
- /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager
- /etc/kubernetes/scheduler
- any kubeconfigs you have written

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use multi master in Kubernetes, you need to use load balancer for high availability.

Please check the official document for detailed steps.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/high-availability/